# White line appearing when viewport is odd number of pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to achieve a layout where I have an outer row with 2 columns of 50% width, with the left column containing 3x2 images & the right column containing a single image. Whilst Firefox displays this layout fine, however, Chrome & IE display a white line when the viewport is an odd number of pixels wide. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? I'm leaning towards Chromium bug at this point, having spent many hours trying all sorts of solutions (playing with flexbox, positioning, font-size, line-height etc.).

CodePen: https://codepen.io/richard-clarke/pen/RwBKXYQ

```css
.img div {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img.img-lg div {
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid g-0">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 img">
          <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/768')"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 img img-lg">
      <div style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/2304x1536')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is worse on the real site in that the white line appears on any number of sides of any of the images & is not restricted to odd pixels, as in the below image. I suspect that resolving this for the CodePen example would resolve all of the issues on the real site.

[image: Lines showing on multiple sides]

Edit:

Adding my current solution here. It's horrible & not really what I would call a solution, but it achieves the seamless effect on the images that I am looking for. Time to move onto something else & come back to this if I have time.

[image: Current solution]

Comment: You're seeing sub-pixel rounding issues due to the mathematical conflict between the aspect ratios and the screen size constraints. You might try a full flex layout, enforcing the aspect ratio on the outer container element rather than the individual image wrappers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @isherwood. I have tried setting the aspect ratio on the cols instead of the images and either using position absolute with left / right / top / bottom set to 0 or flex approach on the images but the issue still persists. However setting left / right / top / bottom to -1px seemed to do the trick. It's yucky - I absolutely *hate* such hacky approaches - but I've spent so long trying to resolve this & still have plenty to do so it will have to do for now.

Comment: I don't see this issue in Chrome, maybe it's only visible on monitors with a lower pixel density such as 72 DPI? Or it's an anti-aliasing setting in your own browser?

Comment: Whatever it is, everyone in my team has the same issue, and it's an issue both at work & at home (5 monitors total on my side). Looking at the widths in the Computed tab, the col-lg-6 outer col is 951.500 whereas the 3 col-lg-4s are 317.156. 3x 317.156 is 951.468 so there is .032px missing. There's no padding or margin on anything.

Comment: I only see one vertical line in Chrome, and it appears intermittently on size adjustment. It's definitely a problem.

Comment: That's only the basic, cut down version. The real version has a random number of lines (sometimes differing number per row) at various viewport sizes. It's actually Chrome & Edge behaving this way, btw, not IE. They're both Chromium based so should probably raise a bug report.